# Draw arrow on first line passed into style function in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

So I am using the OpenLayers3 example [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/line-arrows.html) and it is working fine, however I do not want to draw an arrow on every single line. Only the very first one that is drawn. Here is what I currently have for my style function.

```
navigationLineStyleFunction: function(feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var lineColor = '#c1005d'
    var styles = [
        new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                //this can accept rgba colors to hide the lines
                color: lineColor,
                width: 6
            })
        })
    ];
    geometry.forEachSegment(function(start, end, sexting) {
        var dx = start[0] - end[0];
        var dy = start[1] - end[1];
        var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        // arrows
        styles.push(new ol.style.Style({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(start),
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/examples/data/arrow.png',
                anchor: [0.75, 0.5],
                rotateWithView: true,
                rotation: -rotation
            })
        }));
    });

    return styles;
}
```

The issue is with the `forEachSegment()` I THINK, but cannot find a function that only grabs the first one. I tried to hack it together by wrapping the `.push()` in an `if` statement that checked for the length of `styles[]` but that did not work. I also tried replacing `forEachSegment()` with `.once()` but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `forEachSegment` method write a custom code to fetch the first 2 coordinates from geometry then apply the styling in this case for that line Segment.
Since `forEachSegment` method's callback will be called for each segment while leads to unnecessary looping.

I have taken a sample from Openlayers site to demonstrate this.

**Fix :**

```
      var coords = geometry.getCoordinates();// Gets all the coordinates
      var start = coords[0];//First Coordinate
      var end = coords[1];//Second Coordinate

      // Rest of the code
      var dx = end[0] - start[0];
      var dy = end[1] - start[1];
      var rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      // arrows
      styles.push(new ol.style.Style({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(end),
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.0.1/examples/data/arrow.png',
          anchor: [0.75, 0.5],
          rotateWithView: true,
          rotation: -rotation
        })
      }));
```

Look at this plunckr [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/5qN1nLvVwOqTBOyBl7SD?p=preview)